# Tab system using panels

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, panel

I'm trying to make it to where a panel becomes visible and it sent to the front so it can be seen and interacted with, like this.

```
private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SettingsPanel.Visible = true;
    SettingsPanel.BringToFront();
}
```

The problem is that after clicking a few of the buttons, it will either display the wrong panel or none at all. Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: Before y'all ask, i'm using WinForms.

Comment: I'm assuming that there are controls on your panel. I'm also guessing that you want to selectively control the visibility of the panel and the controls it contains. You probably don't want to be playing games with the Z-Order of your panel. That controls which control is front-most. As a guess, if you _Bring to Front_ a panel, it will hide the controls it contains. What I'd do is change the panel's visibility and the iterate the panel's Controls collection, changing the viability of each of those controls. Remember,  WinForms is just a thin wrapper around the Win32 APIs.

Comment: @FlyDog57 I don't understand a word you're saying, but there aren't any controls on the panel yet and the whole panel disappears, not the controls.

Comment: Controls on a form have a Z-Order. Think of them like cards in a deck. The first card you put down may get partially covered by the next card. When you say BringToFront, you are picking up a card from where it was and dropping on the top. The Visibility property controls whether the control is drawn or hidden. Lay everything out (x, y, and z) and just play with visibility. In WinForms, Panels contain other controls. But, under the covers, everything is controlled by Windows, and all controls are peers. That's why I think playing with a panel's Z-order will mess things up

Comment: Oh, and all WinForms controls have a Controls property that represents the collection of controls that that particular control "contains". So one you put controls in your panel, if you hide the panel, I don't think the contained controls will be hidden (but, maybe they will be). If they aren't hidden, you can ripple the hidden-ness down by changing the Visibility of the controls in the Panel's Controls collection

Comment: @Flydog57 I don't understand any of this at all :(

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I was wrong, WinForms is smarter than I thought.  Here's a test you can do.  I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but this should help you along.  To start, we're going to build a small WinForms app.  With one exception, we aren't going to set any properties of the controls we drop on the screen:

1. Create a new WinForms app
2. In the designer, drop a Panel (which will be named `panel1`) on the form
3. In the properties pane, set the `BorderStyle` to FixedSingle (that's the only property we are going to set)
4. Make two copies of that panel (`panel2` and `panel3`).  Position them so that panels do not overlap at all.
5. On each panel drop a couple of controls (I put labels (labels 1-3) and textboxes (also 1-3)) on each one
6. Beside each panel (arranged so that there is no overlap) drop three buttons on the form (buttons 1-3) make it so that visually, each button is associated with the similarly numbered panel
7. Duplicate `panel3` including its contained controls (so that you get `panel4`, `label4` and `textbox4`).  Position the duplicate so that it significantly overlaps panel 3

Now we're going to look at the code that the designer creates for your form.  Don't mess with this code (you can, but if you don't know what you are doing, it can turn out bad - and, we're keeping this simple).

1. In the Solution Explorer click the unfilled triangle to the left of **Form1.cs**.  Note that it rotates and turns solid.  Also note that Form1.Designer.cs is displayed.  That's a normally hidden source file that contains all the designer created code that corresponds with the form and the controls you dropped on it.
2. Open **Form1.Designer.cs**
3. Click the little grey plus sign icon next to `Windows Form Designer generated code`
4. Inspect the file.  Note that every action you did in the designer has a corresponding line of code in the Designer.cs file (more or less)
5. Look at the code for one of the panels (say `panel1`).

See that it includes:

```
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
```

6. Scroll all the way down to the `Form1` code and see that the panels and buttons get added to the Form's Controls collection:

Like:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
this.Controls.Add(this.panel4);
this.Controls.Add(this.panel3);
this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
```

Note that the order is reversed.  The order is important, it sets the Z-Order (i.e., what overlaps what) for the form and the controls on the form.

**Wiring up the buttons**

Select all three buttons and press `<Enter>`.  This will open the **Form1.cs** file and generate three button click handlers that you can fill in.

Use this code for the three button handlers:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     var wasVisible = panel1.Visible;
     panel1.Visible = !wasVisible;
 }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     panel2.BringToFront();
 }

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     panel3.BringToFront();
 }
```

The first one will toggle the first panel's visibility (I put in an extra variable so you can set a breakpoint and see what's going on).  The second one brings `panel2` to the front, changing its Z-Order (it's called Z-Order because the position on the screen is measure in X and Y, which the overlap position is related to the "depth" of the screen, or the Z-coordinate).  The last one does the same thing to `panel3`.

Run the program.

- When you press the first button, the first panel and its controls disappear (this surprised me, WinForms is smarter than I thought)
- When you press the second button, nothing appears to happen.  This is because the only thing that `panel2` intersects is the form, and `panel2` already covers the form, so you don't see any effect. (and because WinForms is smarter than I thought)
- When you press the third button, `panel2` (and it's controls) jump to the front of the stack of controls, covering the intersecting part of `panel4`.

Does this help you understand how `Visible` and `BringToFront()` work?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is similar to a `TabControl` alternative. Here's an example:

[image: Tabs alternative]

You can manage the current panel simply by making it visible and docked to fill. Hide the other panels.

```
public partial class FormTabsAlternative
    : Form
{
    int         m_current = 0;
    List<Panel> m_tabs    = new List<Panel>();

    public FormTabsAlternative()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AddTab(pnl1);
        AddTab(pnl2);
        AddTab(pnl3);
        AddTab(pnl4);

        SetUpTabsAndButtons();
    }

    private void AddTab(Panel pnl)
    {
        m_tabs.Add(pnl);

        pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void OnLeftClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_current > 0)
        {
            m_current--;

            SetUpTabsAndButtons();
        }
    }

    private void OnRightClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_current < m_tabs.Count - 1)
        {
            m_current++;

            SetUpTabsAndButtons();
        }
    }

    private void SetUpTabsAndButtons()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < m_tabs.Count; index++)
        {
            var panel     = m_tabs[index];

            panel.Visible = index == m_current;
        }

        btnLeft .Enabled = m_current > 0;
        btnRight.Enabled = m_current < m_tabs.Count - 1;
    }
}
```